# Link page post layout is different for post created with the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

When creating unpublished (dark) link posts with Graph API, we are setting the "picture" parameter to override the thumbnail Facebook retrieves from the link url. The post we create this way has a thumbnail size of 90*90 on the old newsfeed design, while the posts created in Power Editor with the identical image has a thumbnail size of 400*210.

In the new news feed design posts created both methods look the same. Any idea how to fix this issue in the old new feed design?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum format for the image in page post links ads is now 600x315. Images below this size will not render correctly.

When creating posts via the Power Editor, I believe images are resized and scaled to make sure they render correctly, however this does not happen through the Ads API as the assumption is you know what you want to do.

** Edit **
I think you're confusing how a story renders in feed vs how it renders on timeline. Unpublished page posts may use the old rendering on tineline, however that's not important as it's not accessed that way, however uses the correct rendering on newsfeed.

e.g.
Timeline:

[image]

Newsfeed (old design):

[image]

Comment: That makes sense, but when we try this image: http://imgur.com/6LDTksa we still get the same difference of thumbnail between Power Editor and the API. Do you know if 600*315 is still the suggested size?

Comment: technically double that size is the recommended as it will render at high resolution in mobile newsfeed. Are you looking at the post on newsfeed or on a page's timeline?

Comment: The difference is on the old newsfeed design, I visit the posts permanent link to preview. https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/597440166958230/ I filed this bug report since the image complies suggested dimentions.