# Page link posts created with image renders with small image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-ads-api

Page link posts have two formats: old with small image and new one with bigger image. Take two posts as example: https://www.facebook.com/77test/posts/10151843713945847 and https://www.facebook.com/77test/posts/10151843715495847.

When created through API, image in most cases is rendered in small format. When Power Editor is used image is always rendered as big (if it was big enough when uploaded). We are not re-sizing image when uploading through API.

Any clue why API could behave like this? How to upload image so that it always treated properly?

Corresponding bug report on FB: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/573150729421730/

We are making POST request to PAGE_ID/feed uploading image together with post creation request via 'thumbnail' property.

Comment: _“When created through API, image in most cases is rendered in small format.”_ – what I have read so far, this is a limitation that Facebook imposes on posts made via API, since they consider those less “relevant” than posts made via the website UI itself (or power editor). It may change at some point in the future. But as of now there is not much you can do about it (apart from providing images that are big enough/have the right aspect ratio, just in case).

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243176/link-page-post-layout-is-different-for-post-created-with-the-graph-api/20247904#20247904